# Firebase Not Adding some Values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Below is the data which i want to upload on the firebase database

```
{email=t@t.com, name=david ,photoUrl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOLT.png}
```

In the registration screen I follow the below step in order to register the user:

1. create user with email
2. login the user
3. add information of the user

---

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.inputEmail.getText().toString(),binding.inputPwd.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(binding.inputEmail.getText().toString(),binding.inputPwd.getText().toString())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                            storeuserdata();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            hideProgressDialog();
                                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });


    public void storeuserdata(){
    mUserRefrence.child(uid).setValue(postValues)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                hideProgressDialog();
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, getString(R.string.login_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                finish();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

But when I view the database it always skips `photourl` values and `name` key with value.

```
users{
  Ul95OXiNhCM5ydpbdvWC5sfnykz2
    email: "t@t.com"
   photoUrl: ""}
```

If you observe the above result the `name` key with value is missing and `photoUrl` value is also missing.

Below is the postvalue data

```
  D/SignUpActivity: storeUserData() called postValues : {email=t@t.com, name=david, photoUrl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOLT.png}
```

Below is the model class

```
class UserData {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String photoUrl;

    public UserData() {

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public UserData(String name, String email, Uri photoUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.photoUrl=photoUrl.toString();
    }


    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("email", email);
        result.put("photoUrl",photoUrl);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide postValues variable Data

Comment: {email=t@t.com, name=david ,photoUrl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOLT.png}

Comment: I show that first line but you might be missing something is your model class is

class model{
String email;
String photoUrl;
}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your insertion but there may be the problem with your model class's value print Model class value with the log to test.

Comment: I have printed the log value and everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

try addOnCompleteListener instead of addOnSuccessListener,

```
 mUserRefrence.child(uid).setValue(postValues)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Void aVoid) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, getString(R.string.login_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            });
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: check it once without finishing the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` which is correct no issue with it but there is no need to `signInWithEmailAndPassword` because when you `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` That means you don't need to authenticate the user again user already been sign in in your app better add `AuthStateListener` to your `FirebaseAuth` instead of saving data inside `onComplete` method.

```
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {

       storeuserdata();
    } 
}
```